# Issue with query string outside bin - debug

Tags: apache-flex

As in topic, this is working fine in bin debug, but now outside

I use this code:

```
bm = BrowserManager.getInstance();
bm.init("","Welcome!");
var o:Object = URLUtil.stringToObject(bm.fragment, "&");
first.text = o.firstPar;
```

Comment: OT: don't post in the answer part.. cause its not an answer.. just edit your question, ang remove the below answer

Answer (score 0):

event this not workign in bin-release

```
first.text = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");
```

but it is working really great in bin-debug

Comment: try first.text = ExternalInterface.call("eval", "window.location.href");

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the HTML in bin-debug to bin-release.. if not, try copying it and open again. maybe you coded the javascript in bin-debug but not in bin-release

Answer (score 0):

Solution was that I can't run flex and read query par on local, there is need to run in on localhost or on remote server